# Variadic signals and generic lambdas

Tags: qt, c++11, signals-slots, c++17, generic-lambda

Is it possible to create variadic *signal* and *connect* generic lambda as *slot*? I mean something like (say, all definitions of involved functions are visible where needed (e.g. at points of instantiation)):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTime>

class A
    : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public :

    A(QObject * const parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QObject{parent}
    { ; }

signals :

    template< typename ...Ts >
    void infoMessage(Ts... args);

public slots :

    void run()
    {
        emit infoMessage("Started at ", QTime::currentTime());
    }

};

#include <QTimer>
#include <QtDebug>

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    QCoreApplication a{argc, argv};
    A a;
    auto printInfoMessage = [&] (auto... args)
    {
        (qInfo() << ... << args);
    };
    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(infoMessage), printInfoMessage);
    QTimer::singleShot(0, &a, &A::run);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Currently it gives an error message:

> AUTOGEN: error: process for main.cpp:18: Error: Template function as signal or slot
>
> moc failed...

Here macro `SLOT()` instead of `&A::infoMessage` does not help a lot. Is there any workarounds to overcome this limitation?

I know, that some of the answers will contain a using of `std::make_tuple` and `std::index_sequence` stuff. But is there less verbose solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct workaround for having template. On of thea reason is that the moc indexes all signals and slots, and this cannot be done for function templates as function templates will generate several functions depending code that is generally not accessible from the moc.

I don't think you can make it work with tuple and such as these are also templates.

A solution could be to use QVariant and/or QVariantList for your arguments.

---

Please note that the error is not caused by the `QObject::connect` line, but the the signal declaration in class A.

Also, you cannot replace `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` at your will, it is either a signal **or** a slot, it cannot be both.

And finally you should be using this form:

```
QObject::connect(&a, &A::infoMessage, printInfoMessage);
```

And since printInfoMessage is using auto parameters, you might need to force the auto resolution using `qOverload`:

```
QObject::connect(&a, &A::infoMessage, qOverload<QVariantList>(printInfoMessage));
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to collect all the variants of instantiation of member function on `emit someSignal(...);` points and then generate all the corresponding specializations right before linking?

Comment: No. The `moc` is called before any compilation is done and only process files which have the Q_OBJECT macro. The output of the moc is C++ code that is compiled at the same time your own C++ files are compiled. So link time is far too late for the moc to add any function. But link time is also far too soon to know any use cases of your template function (e.g is you are building a library, the binary that will use your library will generate there own functions based on your template)

Comment: What do you think: is it possible to overcome all these limitations when static reflection became avaliable? Or maybe some parts of `clang` infrastructure can help here?

Comment: BTW it seems that there is no need to use `qOverload<QVariantList>` at all.

Comment: I do not know, but even when static reflection will be available, you will need to wait for the Qt devs to change the way the moc works. And because of Qt backward compatibility of ABI, I do not see this happening in a minor Qt release. So it may take a few more years.

Comment: "few more years" sounds bad =). Thank you.